# Have twitter bot retrieve username upon new follow action javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-follow

I am making a twitter bot. When someone follows the bot, I would like to send a tweet out that says Thankyou "@their username" for the follow, or something along those lines. How do I get the account's username on the follow event?

Before this was done using the "stream" function but that was discontinued. Does anyone know of a functioning workaround that would allow me to do what I just described in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's developer site has [a tutorial](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/twitter-account-activity-tutorial-autohook) which describes using the [NPM autohook package](https://github.com/twitterdev/autohook) to build a responder. You'll want to look out for `follow_events` and respond with a Direct Message.

```js
webhook.on('event', async event => {
      if (event.follow_events) {
        await sayHi(event);
      }
    });
```

Even if you do take that approach, I'd be careful about running something like this, as a lot of people find this kind of approach a bit spammy. A reminder that the Developer Policy and Twitter Rules have [guidance](https://blog.twitter.com/en_au/topics/company/2019/Spamm-ybehaviour-and-platform-manipulation-on-Twitter.html) about not sending large numbers of unsolicited mentions.

Comment: Hello! Thankyou for your input. However I am not looking to send a direct message to someone who follows. I am looking to compose and send a new tweet using their username. Is it only possible to to retrieve their username via a direct message?

Comment: No, you will get the username from the `follow_event`. Using Direct Messages for this communication in an automated manner is considered less spam-like than a public Tweet. Using public Tweets for unsolicited mentions is against the Twitter policy and is likely to lead to your app being restricted.